# Kotlin Multiplatform: Compile Kotlin to JS, then use JS methods

Tags: javascript, kotlin, multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin multiplatform setup including a JS and Java part. In the common folder I wrote a couple of methods that should be compiled to js. Such as:

```
class test {
    init {
         println("this is completely working")
     }
}
```

Now when I build my project, in the JS-exclusive folder there is a node_modules folder generated including the example from above (although I expected Kotlin to convert `println` to `console.log` which it did not). Now I would like to include this file and its method for another JS file to read from. How could that be done? Unfortunately there isn't a lot of documentation on these multiplatform topics and I struggle to get the most basic things done.

Comment: Please state the version of kotlin you are using, and if possible, post your build.gradle(.kts) too configuration too

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the script that is generated by the Kotlin/JS compiler.

Both SharedCode.js and BluetoothSerial.js were generated by the Kotlin/JS compiler.

```
<head>
    <title>WebView Callback Demo</title>
    <script src="js/kotlin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SharedCode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <script src="js/BluetoothSerialJs.js"></script>

</body>
```

https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/cordova-alternative-pattern/blob/3208b24b839db6f01a27d0d5fda15cd80a4a0d12/app/src/main/assets/index.html#L4-L15

You can then call the javascript functions that were generated like this:

PackageName.Module.Function() <- you might need to include class name

```
com.fivestars.bluetooth.BluetoothSerial.configureChannel()
```

A sample project is here:

https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/cordova-alternative-pattern